# Can I programming a CPLD in low-level?

Tags: fpga, programming, programmable-logic

Maybe it's a silly question, but I want to use a microcontroller with a CPLD.

My idea is for the microcontroller to reprogram the CPLD as many times as the user wants.

The problem is that I don't want to use a software provided by the manufacturer, I want to create my own software tool.

Is it a crazy idea?

It is something similar to this project:

[HOW-TO: PROGRAMMABLE LOGIC DEVICES (CPLD)](https://hackaday.com/2008/12/11/how-to-programmable-logic-devices-cpld/)

Comment: Vendors already support this, and I don't see why you think you need PC software to get a microcontroller to reprogram a CPLD (or FPGA). You just program the microcontroller to follow the steps provided by the vendor. FPGAs support this, and any CPLD or FPGA that uses external flash memory can support this. If it's a device that has internal flash memory (like many CPLDs) then you will have to dig into the documentation to see whether details are provided on how to program it. But you don't need PC software.

Comment: Supposing that I want to create software for the user to create a project in FBD (block diagram) or ladder, I must know how to interpret the blocks that the user wrote, to convert it into "code" for the CLPD

Comment: That is completely unrelated to your actual post about a microcontroller re-programming a CPLD. Those are synthesis tools, not configuring the CPLD from a microcontroller (or even from the PC).

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you just want to make a CPLD programmer that uses existing bitstreams, or do you want to actually design the CPLD in your microprocessor or what?

Comment: If you have experience designing optimal 100 IC boards as I did in the late 70’s then, no problem. Compile code and then make it better with discrete. Or visa versa. But designing your own compiler fuggedaboudit , unless you have more compiler training and experience than Microchip

Comment: Based on the expertise of your questions so far, it’s a good idea but you’re not ready.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 You are right. I made a software to create a project in FBD (block diagram) that is downloaded to a microcontroller. In other words, all the blocks that the user puts in the project are converted into assembly instructions and then a hexadecimal file is created that is downloaded to the MCU's program memory.  My idea now is to do the same with a CPLD or FPGA.

Comment: @FabiánRomo gigantic project, orders of magnitude harder. For a microcontroller, your vendor gives you an instruction set documentation. For an FPGA, they try to keep their bitstream format simple. For a programming language, there's already functioning frontends for which you "only" need to add an assembler backend; for hardware synthesis, you need to build very complex logic to convert logic statements to a literal multi-thousand-cells 3D floorplan. This is a significantly harder problem than compiling C, both practically and from a computational complexity point of view.

Comment: @FabiánRomo People did that, after studying this kind of things, in their PhD and over years after. Simon Richter's answer points you to open source FPGA toolchains. You should really look at Yosys, abc and nextPNR (yosys has been explained in multiple excellent talks). See whether doing something similar is really in scope for you!

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

1. Most CPLDs have embedded flash for programming, so the number of times they can be reprogrammed is limited by the memory
2. The bitstream you need to send is usually built with a commercial compiler.

The thing that comes closest to what you want are FPGAs with an open source toolchain. FPGAs and CPLDs are very similar, but have a slightly different weighting between logic gates and registers, and most FPGAs are configured with SRAM that can be reprogrammed arbitrarily often without wearing out like flash.

Take a look at open source FPGA toolchains to see what chips are supported and what is required to run them. You want a machine that is strong enough to run the toolchain to get a programming file, an interface that allows you to send the file to the FPGA, and an interface to transfer data between CPU and FPGA.

Comment: Atmel ATF15xx CPLDs can be programmed at least 10,000 times, the same endurance rating as the ATmega328 in an Arduino.

Comment: @BruceAbbott, for manual deployment during development, that is plenty. For an automated process that reprograms the device as needed, that might be on the small side.